# How SQLAlchemy's many to many inserts work?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to understand how to insert "many-to-many" records in database using raw SQL properly, but couldn't find any examples, so I decided to see what SQLAlchemy would generate:

I've created my python objects models:

python objects model (**models.py**):

```py
import typing

from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class OrderLine:
    """Item amount + SKU in order"""

    order_id: int
    amount: int
    sku: str


class Batch:
    """Batch of items."""

    def __init__(self, batch_name: str, amount: int, sku: str, eta: typing.Optional[datetime.datetime]):
        self.batch_name = batch_name
        self.available_quantity = amount
        self.sku = sku
        self.eta = eta

        self._allocations = set()

    def allocate(self, order_line: OrderLine):
        self._allocations.add(order_line)
```

- tables and sqlalchemy's mappers (**tables.py**):

```py
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, Integer, String, Date, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, relationship


import models


metadata = MetaData()

order_lines = Table(
    "order_lines",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("order_id", Integer),
    Column("amount", Integer, nullable=False),
    Column("sku", String(255)),
)

batches = Table(
    "batches",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("batch_name", String(255)),
    Column("available_quantity", Integer),
    Column("sku", String(255)),
    Column("eta", Date, nullable=True)
)

allocations = Table(
    "allocations",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("batch_id", ForeignKey("batches.id")),
    Column("orderline_id", ForeignKey("order_lines.id"))
)


def map_objects_to_tables():
    lines_mapper = mapper(models.OrderLine, order_lines)
    mapper(models.Batch, batches, properties={
        "_allocations": relationship(
            lines_mapper, secondary=allocations, collection_class=set
        )
    })
```

Now if I try to save an object using an ORM:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

import models
import tables



engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:", echo=True)
tables.metadata.create_all(engine)
tables.map_objects_to_tables()


example_batch = models.Batch("test", 1000, "WHITE DOOR", None)
example_line = models.OrderLine(1, 50, "WHITE DOOR")
example_batch.allocate(example_line)

session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

session.add(example_batch)
session.commit()
```

sqlalchemy produces following output:

```sql
BEGIN (implicit)
  INSERT INTO batches (batch_name, available_quantity, sku, eta) VALUES ('test', 1000, 'WHITE DOOR', null)
  INSERT INTO order_lines (order_id, amount, sku) VALUES (1, 50, 'WHITE DOOR')
  INSERT INTO allocations (batch_id, orderline_id) VALUES (1, 1)
COMMIT

BEGIN (implicit)
  SELECT order_lines.id AS order_lines_id, order_lines.order_id AS order_lines_order_id, order_lines.amount AS order_lines_amount, order_lines.sku AS order_lines_sku 
  FROM order_lines 
  WHERE order_lines.id = 1
```

How SQLAlchemy knows when inserting into `allocations`, that `batch_id` and `orderline_id` should be (1, 1)? Does it somehow manages those values inside if foreign key maps to an autoincrement?

What is the point of last select?

Comment: Your example code uses tables but the output you say uses the orm.  Can you post the saving code you used?

Comment: @IanWilson It's just 2 python classes with respectitive fields and sqlalchemy mapping functions. I've updated my answer. Also i've found in documentation that autoincrement fields are ```considered to be available using an “autoincrement” method specific to the backend database, such as calling upon cursor.lastrowid, using RETURNING in an INSERT statement to get at a sequence-generated value, or using special functions such as “SELECT scope_identity()”``` So my guess is sqlalchemy is indeed manages those fields internally, may be wrong though.